# Laravel Validation - Either 2 of 3 textboxes required

Tags: php, laravel, validation

I am trying to get 2 of 3 textboxes to be filled

```
'name' => 'required_with:email,id',
'id' => 'required_with:name,email',
'email' => 'required_with:name,id',
```

Any help is much appreciated!!

Comment: you need a custom validator https://laravel.com/docs/5.7/validation#custom-validation-rules

Answer (score 0):

Because you put on all the field the validation rules required_with the other two field It will force all fields to be required and you will not be abol to save any entry without filling all three field.

To achive what you want you must put required_with only with one field and not both all remainin

You can put the email required with the name, I will discourage you to make require_with:id on any field because the id is an auto increment field. Unless you create a custom primary key and set public $incrementing = false;